# How can I conditionally nest routes with go_router based on screen size?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-go-router

I'm developing a Flutter app using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) for navigation, and I've encountered a responsive design scenario that is quite common, but I can't find a straightforward way to handle the routing.

### Simplified scenario

- The app has three top-level routes: `/home`, `/posts`, and `/profile`
- Each of these routes can be accessed through top-level navigation: a [bottom navigation bar](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/guidelines) on compact screens, a [navigation rail](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-rail/overview) on medium screens, and a persistent [navigation drawer](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-drawer/overview) on expanded screens
- The navigation UI remains persistent when animating transitions between the top-level routes

Now, let's say within `/posts`, when a user selects a specific post with an ID, they navigate to the post details at `/posts/ID`.

### Behavior I'm looking for

- On compact screens, the post details view takes up the entire screen, transitioning over the top of the bottom navigation bar, hiding it until the user navigates back
- On larger screens, the persistent navigation sidebar/rail should remain, with only the inner content of the screen updating to show the post details
- The ideal solution would:

  1. use go_router's [type-safe routes](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Type-safe%20routes-topic.html)
  2. Seamlessly transition between each layout type when resizing the screen

### What I've tried

I'm using a `ShellRoute` to display the persistent navigation. I know that I can specify a route's `parentNavigatorKey` to use the root navigator instead of the shell, but I'm not sure how I can dynamically change this setting based on the current screen size.

Is there a way to conditionally make a route nested or top-level in go_router based on screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

- I had a similar problem, but I didn't tailor it to your answer so there are some things that need to be changed
- It may not be the most efficient solution to the problem
- I also didn't use type safe-routes, but you should easily be able to make the required changes

1. I created a GoRouter in which I separated the different device widths into different Routes

```dart
  final GoRouter goRouter = GoRouter(
      initialLocation: "/mobile",
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      redirect: (context, state) {
        MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
        return navigatorService.navigate(state, mediaQuery);
      },
      routes: [
        ShellRoute(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
              return ChatNavigator(child: child);
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                  parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                  path: '/desktop',
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return const Nothing();
                  },
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                      parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                      path: 'chat/:id',
                      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                       final id = state.pathParameters['id'];
                        return Chat(
                          id: id == "null" ? null : int.parse(id!),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    GoRoute(
                      parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                      path: 'settings',
                      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                        return const Settings();
                      },
                    ),
                  ]),
            ]),
        GoRoute(
            path: "/mobile",
            parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ChatNavigator(
                child: SizedBox.shrink(),
              );
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: 'chat/:id',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  final id = state.pathParameters['id'];
                  return Chat(
                    id: id == "null" ? null : int.parse(id!),
                  );
                },
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: 'settings',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return const Settings();
                },
              ),
            ]),
      ]);
```

The problem here is also that you have duplicate routes, to solve that you could put them into a List and just attach it to the different routes.
2. What you can also see is that I used the redirect method of the GoRouter, there I will intercept every push or replace request. Because I created multiple routes with the same content I somehow need to translate these general requests, i.e.: `GoRouter.of(context).push('/chat/${widget.chat.id}');`
3. For that I created a Class that handles these requests:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class NavigatorService {
  String? lastRoute;
  String navigate(GoRouterState state, MediaQueryData mediaQuery) {
    lastRoute = state.uri.toString().contains("/desktop") ||
            state.uri.toString().contains("/mobile")
        ? lastRoute
        : state.uri.toString();
  
    String path = state.uri.toString().replaceAll("/desktop", '').trim();
    String changed = path.replaceAll("/mobile", "").trim();
    if (mediaQuery.size.width >= 700.0) {
      // Desktop Route
      if (state.uri.toString().contains("/mobile")) {
        return "/desktop$lastRoute";
      }
      return "/desktop$changed";
    } else {
      //Mobile
      if (state.uri.toString().contains("/desktop")) {
        return "/mobile$lastRoute";
      }
      return "/mobile$changed";
    }
  }
}
```

5. This class is instantiated before the GoRouter

```dart
  static NavigatorService navigatorService = NavigatorService();

  final GoRouter goRouter = GoRouter(
  ....
```

I hope this idea helps you!

I've also foung a package made by Google, which should do what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_navigation